Who was the French detective mentioned in Hitchcock's "Shadow of a Doubt"?
Here's a little bit of context from Shadow of a Doubt (1943):

Herbert Hawkins: That little Frenchman beats them all. You can talk
all you like about Sherlock Holmes. That little Frenchman beats them
all.
Joseph Newton: I read it. Air bubbles don't necessarily kill a person.
Those writers from the other side get too fancy. The best way to
commit a murder...
Herbert Hawkins: I know. I know. Hit them on the head with a blunt
instrument.

Obviously, Herbert is comparing Sherlock Holmes to another famous detective, described as a little Frenchman in the film. The only French detective I can think of is Monsieur Lecoq, but I can't find any evidence to prove that. Any idea who this mysterious Frenchman is?

For years, people thought Hercule Poirot was French...

I thought of him too, but he's Belgian. And again, I can't find any proof.

The year before the aforementioned movie, Poirot found Amyas Crale's murderer by 'just reading testimonies', and it's a multiple-layered twisted plot, with coniine used as a murder weapon. Here, "air bubbles" probably refers to any "soft" way of killing, such as poisoning.

Yes, he's from Belgium, but has a very thick french accent. And, at that time, anyone speaking french was labeled as French, even by mistake. Plus, who would think about a Belgian hero?

In Murder by Death (1976) famous detective Milo Perrier is a pastiche of Hercule Poirot.  Somebody called him "Frenchie" and he says he's "a  Belgie".  So apparently it was common enough to think Poirot was French instead of Belgian to make a joke about it.

It can't be it, because Shadow of a Doubt came out in 1943.

I wonder why noone has mentioned C. Auguste Dupin yet. I thought he was French, too.

@NapoleonWilson: good catch! didn't think of him, but seems "too old" to be a reference for the 1943 movie.

@JConstantine  Murder by Death (1976) parodies detectives in the Thin Man series 1934-1947, The Maltese Falcon novel (1930)  & films (1931, 1936, 1941) the Miss Marple novels (1930-1976),  The Charlie Chan novels (1925-1932) & films  (1926-1949), and the Hercule Poirot books (1920-1997).   Everyone parodied in Murder by Death  (1976) was famous by 1943, so your objection about it being 33 years after Shadow of a doubt is highly illogical.

@OldPadawan Maigret also seems to be a contender in theory as 22 novels seem to have been published up to and including 1940 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Maigret

@MD-Tech: actually, they could (almost) all match (Rouletabille, Maigret), because they're all wise and smart. What makes me pick Poirot is that (beside my other arguments) he's the only one to be of a small stature. Were it Maigret, one would probably say "that old frenchman" for instance, as any of them has a typical physical detail that characterises him.

@M.A.Golding - There's a line in one of Peter Ustinov's Poirot film where a woman calls him a "French upstart", and he replies "Please, Belgian upstart, madame..."

This is the aformentioned scene (and the script at the same page/stage):



The books Herbert Hawkins holds are probably "Murder Mystery(ies)" and "Unsolved Crime Stories".

Now, my 2 cents for a frame-challenge. This isn't a French detective this is all about, but a Belgian one, the Belgian one: Mister Hercule Poirot.
Not only was he the most famous detective of the era (1930 - 1950) (Shadow of a doubt is a 1943 movie), but he was also often mistaken with a French.
His style his all softness and roundness, nothing like the described scene.
For years, people thought Hercule Poirot was French, because he has a very thick french accent (and no one ever thought such a character would come from such a 'small unknown country'1). And, at that time, anyone speaking French was (even mistakenly) labeled as French.
Beside that, what makes me pick Poirot (amongst other candidates) is that he's the only one to be of a small stature, therefore, using "little" would be appropriate in the mind of someone who doesn't know more about him.
The year before the aforementioned movie, Poirot found Amyas Crale's murderer by "just reading testimonies", and it's a multiple-layered twisted plot, with coniine used as a murder weapon. Here, "air bubbles" probably refers to any "soft" way of killing, such as poisoning, as opposed as "hit with a bat". There's also a scene where Herbie and Joe talk about using untraceable poison in coffee to kill the other. Like Crale's murder.

1. hope my Wallons grand-parents won't hear that from beyond the grave :)

Poirot is certainly where my mind went first.  Notwithstanding that he's actually Belgian, as you say.

“Air bubbles” may refer to the fictional method of killing someone by injecting them with an empty syringe. In reality, air bubbles in the veins carry a risk of causing heart failure, but the method would be too unreliable, as the characters remark. Not sure whether this trope occurs in any of Poirot books, or they got it confused with some other European detective story.

Just a detail that the answer doesn't explicitly point out: Poirot not only speaks French,  it is a recurring staple of the book (and TV) series that he is constantly called French by people (usually Brits), much to his dismay. Him being called French isn't particularly a mistake on the part of Herbert Hawkins in Shadow of a Doubt, nor is is a mistake made by whoever wrote the script for Shadow of a Doubt; it's referencing something that is canon in the original works featuring Hercule Poirot.

Also, another detail: Poirot is notably short in stature, so there's support for him being called a "little" Frenchman by Herbert Hawkins.

@Flater: agreed. I mention that in a comment on the main post ("What makes me pick Poirot is that (beside my other arguments) he's the only one to be of a small stature.") but didn't think I needed it for the answer
